# Replace word user wrote in Text Box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm typing my first useful code for school right now, (I have about 1-2 years of basic coding knowledge) I know HTML and CSS, but right now I'm getting into JavaScript. I was wondering how by the press of a button, a word a user wrote in an HTML text box replaces with another word. Let's say they wrote:
"I like eating pie." In an HTML textarea element. How can I use JavaScript so I can replace the word "like" with "love" by the click of a button? Sorry if I'm bad at explaining, questions are welcomed!

Comment: Java question tag removed and JavaScript question tag added.  You'll want to be more careful with your tags in the future else you'll not get the right experts to review your question.

Comment: Try looking up the Javascript onclick event and the getElementById function.

Comment: So, on Stack Overflow, we expect people who post a question to have done some research before asking questions. You can see [ask] for more info on that. I would start off by researching "JavaScript event handlers" for information on hooking up code to a button, then "JavaScript string manipulation" for the replacing.

Comment: You're actually asking three or four different questions here. 1) How do I run a javascript function when a button is clicked? 2) How do I get the text string from a textbox? 3) How do I replace a word in a string in javascript? 4) How do I change the text in a textbox in javascript? You should be able to find all those answers with a quick google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote some code that does exactly what you asked for. The code is pretty simple it uses "onclick" to call a function that gets the value of the textarea replace the words (using the "replace" function of javascript) and then changes the value of the textarea with the new value (with the replaced words)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function replace(){
        var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        var newText = text.replace("like", "love");
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = newText;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea"></textarea>
    <button id="button" onclick="replace();">replace</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it help. Anything you can ask.

Comment: One last question, if I copy and paste the "var newText = text.replace("like", "love");" and put it under the original, then click "replace" it only replaces one of them, not both. Any fix?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question, can you explain better

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the id attribute to textbox in form. like:

```
<form>
 <input type="Text" id = "textField">
 <input type = "Button" Value = "Change Text" onclick="ChangeText()">
</form>
```

The javaScript function(ChangeText) should have a statement:

```
document.getElementById('textField').Value= "I love eating pie.";
```

You can also use document.getElementByName().

If you want to change a single word then you can add following in ChangeText() function:

```
var oldtext = document.getElementById('textField').Value;
var newtext = oldText.Replace("like","love");
document.getElementById('textField').Value= newText;
```

Comment: What if I already have a text box? (<textarea id="text3" type="text" name="paragraph_text" style="height:500px; width: 1315px" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>)

Comment: Then you just get the text from text area by document.GetElementById('text3').Value;  Then for replacing use the same syntax oldText.Replace("like","love"); final set it's value to newText by document.getElementById.('text3').Value = newText. If you have a doubt whether to use "InnerHTML" instead of Value, then no you should use Value... Hope it helps...